# Pandas: How to create a computed view of the DataFrame (like SQL Create View)

Tags: python, pandas, finance

I'd like to write a function that would be computed on the DataFrame to transform the Index and return a new transformed dataset.  (Similar to Views in the SQL world).

As an example, I have some historical stock prices that gets appended daily and want to have a Monthly-view of the data.

I kinda like [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29613667/721564).  But ideally I don't want to keep track of stale data.

Comment: I don't think this is a general solution, but in the example you mentioned pandas function [`pd.DataFrame.resample()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) is very helpful. For example, you can do `returns.resample('M').last()` to get the last price of the month for each month.

Comment: When you say "view" do you just mean "function"?