# Pandas convert yearly to monthly

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on pulling financial data, in which some is formatted in yearly and other is monthly.  My model will need all of it monthly, therefore I need that same yearly value repeated for each month.  I've been using this [stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29612705/converting-pandas-dataframe-from-monthly-to-daily) and trying to adapt the code to my data.

Here is my dataframe:

```
df.head()

   date ticker value
0 1999-12-31  ECB/RA6  1.0
1 2000-12-31  ECB/RA6  4.0
2 2001-12-31  ECB/RA6  2.0
3 2002-12-31  ECB/RA6  3.0
4 2003-12-31  ECB/RA6  2.0
```

Here is my desired output first 5 rows:

```
   date ticker value
0 1999-12-31  ECB/RA6  1.0
1 2000-01-31  ECB/RA6  4.0
2 2000-02-28  ECB/RA6  4.0
3 2000-13-31  ECB/RA6  4.0
4 2000-04-30  ECB/RA6  4.0
```

And my code:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m')
df = df.pivot(index='date', columns='ticker')
start_date = df.index.min() - pd.DateOffset(day=1)
end_date = df.index.max() + pd.DateOffset(day=31)
dates = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq='M')
dates.name = 'date'
df = df.reindex(dates, method='ffill')

df = df.stack('ticker')
df = df.sortlevel(level=1)
df = df.reset_index()
```

However, it is not repeating the months as expected

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want [**`resample`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html)

First, you need to set the index so that `resample` will work.  Then you backfill and reset the index.

```
df.set_index('date').resample('M').bfill().reset_index()

         date   ticker  value
0  1999-12-31  ECB/RA6    1.0
1  2000-01-31  ECB/RA6    4.0
2  2000-02-29  ECB/RA6    4.0
3  2000-03-31  ECB/RA6    4.0
4  2000-04-30  ECB/RA6    4.0
5  2000-05-31  ECB/RA6    4.0
6  2000-06-30  ECB/RA6    4.0
7  2000-07-31  ECB/RA6    4.0
8  2000-08-31  ECB/RA6    4.0
9  2000-09-30  ECB/RA6    4.0
10 2000-10-31  ECB/RA6    4.0
11 2000-11-30  ECB/RA6    4.0
12 2000-12-31  ECB/RA6    4.0
13 2001-01-31  ECB/RA6    2.0
14 2001-02-28  ECB/RA6    2.0
15 2001-03-31  ECB/RA6    2.0
...
```

---

To handle this per `ticker`

```
df.set_index('date').groupby('ticker', group_keys=False) \
    .resample('M').bfill().reset_index()
```

Comment: I get the error ValueError: cannot reindex a non-unique index with a method or limit

Comment: I think the reason is I have multiple tickers, therefore dates are repeated